# Why Chrome is going to URL in background?

Tags: google-chrome, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have a Java web application and a strange behaviour is taken my sleep today:

After submit my form (a JSP page) I can see other twice calls with null attributes.

```
    public class SubmitFormAction {
        private String adjacency;
        private String laplacian;
        private String slaplacian;
        private String optiFunc;
        private String caixa1;
        private String ordermin;
        private String ordermax;
        private String minDegree;
        private String maxDegree;
        private String triangleFree;
        private String allowDiscGraphs;
        private String biptOnly;


        public String execute () {
            System.out.println(" 1." +adjacency+ " 2." +  laplacian+ " 3." +  slaplacian+ " 4." +  optiFunc+ " 5." +  caixa1+ " 6." +  ordermin+ " 7." +
                     ordermax+ " 8." +  minDegree+ " 9." +  maxDegree+ " 10." +  triangleFree+ " 11." +  allowDiscGraphs+ " 12." +  biptOnly);

    }

}
```

Output after submit a form to this Action:

```
 1.null 2.null 3.null 4.sdfsdf 5.min 6. 7. 8. 9. 10.null 11.null 12.null
 1.null 2.null 3.null 4.null 5.null 6.null 7.null 8.null 9.null 10.null 11.null 12.null
 1.null 2.null 3.null 4.null 5.null 6.null 7.null 8.null 9.null 10.null 11.null 12.null
```

The first output is my submit. Other two is a "phantom" call...
While testing in Chrome, I just write in Chrome address bar the action URL with parameters ( "get" format ) to test a submit without using a page.

Pay attention I NOT PRESS ENTER OR GO TO URL, JUST WRITE and change to Eclipe to check something... now my surprise: A log was registred in Eclipse showing the Action was called, EVEN I NOT GOING TO THAT!!!!

Something makes Chrome follow the address in background...

I just change the action to not go to any page and use a GET request to avoid use of HTML pages in process ( I fear some javascript is doing this ) but nothing changes.

In Firefox and Internet Explorer all goes fine, so the problem is not in my code...

I know ... if not in my code, it is in Chrome and here is not the place to ask about Chrome... but please help!

Comment: Yeap! I have a return in Action Execute method.. just forgot to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type your URL in the Omnibox but wait to press the Enter key, Chrome may pre-fetch and pre-render your page in a hidden tab. During normal web browsing, this prediction mechanism reduces the perception of network latency. The *Privacy > Predict network actions to improve page load performance* option (under *Show advanced settings...*) controls this behavior.

Chrome uses its navigation history to decide when to start pre-fetching a URL; visit `chrome://predictors` to see the data. Your URL likely shows up several times highlighted in green to indicate a high confidence prediction. See https://www.igvita.com/posa/high-performance-networking-in-google-chrome/#omnibox for more details.

One way to verify that Chrome is in fact pre-rendering your page is to watch the **Active Prerender Pages** list in `chrome://net-internals/#prerender` while typing your URL, without pressing Enter, in another tab.

Comment: Wow! Many thanks! It is a very detailed explanation!

Comment: Can this mess with my application? Must I protect my code?